# arrow functions and logging json response to console

Tags: angularjs, api

I call my service and it hits an API and returns a json object. I log the object to console to view the structure of the json object and make sure it returns the data i want.

```
var promise = getJsonObjectService.getJsonObject();

promise.then(function (data) {
    $scope.foo = data;
    console.log($scope.foo);
});
```

I recently learned of Arrow functions and replaced the previous code with this

```
var promise = getJsonObjectService.getJsonObject();

promise.then(data => $scope.foo = data);
```

The json object is returned and the page works the same as before, but I cannot figure out how to log the object to console like the previous method. Can you explain how i would log the json object returned in this arrow function? Can you explain maybe a little about what is happening differently under the hood as between these two code blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way Es6 array function used
`promise.then((data) => {
 $scope.foo = data;
    console.log($scope.foo);
});`

function(params ....){} is replaced by (params) => {} to provide outer function 'this' reference to inside function.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.

```
promise.then(data => {
 $scope.foo = data;
    console.log($scope.foo);
});
```

Hope it helps :)